# Get last deleted ID in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Similar to `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, is there a nice mechanism in MySQL to get the last deleted ID after a row has been deleted?

Comment: Why do you need values that are not longer in database? For a more accurate answer this is a essential issue.

Comment: @daniherrera: I have a table with billions of rows and I want to delete some of them without taking down the server, hence without holding a lock for too long. I've written a script to delete in batches, I need the last deleted id to make the search faster on the next batch.

Comment: I was able to use `returning` with MariaDB, but MySQL users may find this method interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33115929/334493

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By "ID", I assume you mean "auto-increment"?

Since you can delete any arbitrary row (or set of rows) at any time: no, there's no way to tell WHICH row (or rows) you most recently deleted.

You *can*, however, create a "trigger" to save this information for you:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

Answer (score 5):

Instead of creating a trigger, you need to use this each and every time when you delete

```
declare @table1 table(id int identity,name varchar(50))
     insert into @table1 (name)  values('abc')
     insert into @table1 (name)  values('xyz')
      insert into @table1 (name) values('pqr')
       insert into @table1 (name)  values('wqe')
     delete from  @table1 output deleted.name,deleted.id where  id=3
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you make deletions. But if you have an integer id column, you can use the following hack:

```
DELETE FROM users
WHERE login = 'newtover' AND user_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(user_id);

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

But you should make sure that MySQL short-circuits the former condition and does not optimize to run `user_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(user_id)` first. That is you can adjust the query to something like:

```
DELETE FROM users
WHERE login = 'newtover' AND IFNULL(user_id, 0) = LAST_INSERT_ID(user_id);
```

P.S. I do not ask why you might need this. Most probably, you should not want it =)

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be calling your MySQL database from JDBC, then you can execute a `SELECT` and call `ResultSet.deleteRow()` as you read through the results and grab the id's.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Delete {
    public static void main(String... args) throws SQLException {
        try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?user=john&password=denver");
            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("select id from some_table where event=?")
        ) {
            statement.setString(1, "test");
            try(ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery()) {
                System.out.println("deleting id " + result.getLong("id"));
                result.deleteRow();
            }
            conn.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Example table

```
create table some_table(
  id bigint(12),
  event varchar(100)
);

insert into some_table values(1, 'test');
insert into some_table values(2, 'test');
insert into some_table values(3, 'test');
insert into some_table values(4, 'other');
```

Answer (score 0):

The hack with last_insert_id was already mentioned, but that answer 
misses the fact that it could aggregate!

last insert id has fixed size but for small keys it could be used.

```
mysql> insert into t1 () values (),(),(),(),(),(),();
Query OK, 7 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from t1;
+---+
| n |
+---+
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
+---+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
select last_insert_id(0); -- clear accumulator
+-------------------+
| last_insert_id(0) |
+-------------------+
|                 0 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

-- keys will be separated by zeroes
mysql> delete from t1 
        where last_insert_id(last_insert_id() 
                             * pow(10, 2 + floor(log(n)/log(10))) + n)
        limit 6;  
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select last_insert_id();
+------------------+
| last_insert_id() |
+------------------+
|      10203040506 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

-- rows deleted
mysql> select * from t1 limit 1;
+---+
| n |
+---+
| 7 |
+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```