# Insert and select in different queries SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I have a server and many clients, my application is on clients and database on server, i have one table

```
Table -->  Id --> int Auto-increment,   
Name --> nvarchar(50),
```

So, whenever i insert a new row from client with query

```
Insert into Table Name Values('NameValue')
```

It inserts the row and sql auto generates the Id field. So, to fetch its Id, I use the following query

```
Select max(Id) as maxId from Table
```

but both queries are on different connections

It works well when only one client is operating at a time, but when multiple clients are working, Many insert queries are requested by clients before i could request the 'getMaxId' query.

Comment: Why all answer is how to get last ID, if im not mistake Neha Khanna, can get it, and problem is get not correct ID

Comment: could chat about your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

This selects the last-inserted identity.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @a TABLE (
    Id int IDENTITY (1, 1),
    b VARCHAR(1000)
)

DECLARE @b TABLE (
    Id INT
)

INSERT @a (b)
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id INTO @b
SELECT NAME 
FROM sys.objects


SELECT * FROM @a
SELECT * FROM @b
```

Or, you can always use that for retrieving the latest ident:

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('TABLE_NAME')
```

Or use

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Comment: Please check the update, it can be sipmler, but solves your problem

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to run a command to get the recent inserted value.

There are three commands you can run to do that.

[This](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/) link will explain them

the best is

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

because if you have a table A that calls a trigger and this trigger inserts data on a table B, this command will get you the ID of the table A, while @@IDENTITY will get you the id of table B

Comment: see my edit and study the differences between @@IDENTITY and SCOPE_IDENTITY(). This is very important

Answer (score 1):

Rather use:

```
select @@identity
```

instead of `select max(id)...`

It will return the last generated identity for the current connection.

Comment: You need to be careful when using @@identity. Since it's across scopes you could get a value from a trigger, instead of your current statement - http://stackoverflow.com/a/42655/905651

Comment: But with every sql qery, i make a new connection

Answer (score 1):

use this, but it works for PHP

> $id = mysql_insert_id();

and for c#

> Int32 newId = (Int32) myCommand.ExecuteScalar();

Answer (score 0):

Add the following after inserting instead of Max(id) selection.

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Answer (score 0):

Make function in sql, where you will add row and get ID by SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY(). While you call function you will get ID which is exactly added.

Answer (score 0):

try this hope it will may help You

```
  declare @table1 table(id int identity,name varchar(50))
    insert into @table1 (name) output inserted.id  values('abc') 
    insert into @table1 (name) output inserted.id values('xyz')
    insert into @table1 (name) output inserted.id values('pqr')
```

[for more see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583106/get-last-deleted-id-in-mysql/8601728#8601728)