# In MySQL can I return deleted rows after a deletion?

Tags: mysql

How to return deleted records of following query in MySQL?

```sql
DELETE t1
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 on (t1.t2_id = t2.id)
WHERE t2.id IS NULL OR t2.is_valid = false
```

Background:

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.23, for osx10.8 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Comment: As a sujation you can use a select query replace "DELETE" as "SELECT" so you have to "select" before the deleting quary.

Comment: One option could be to use a trigger to capture the deleted rows in a separate table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have the equivalent of the `output` or [`returning`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-delete.html) clauses provided by other databases.  Your best bet is a temporary table:

```
CREATE TABLE TheDeletedIds as
    SELECT t1.id
    FROM t1 LEFT JOIN
         t2 
         ON t1.t2_id = t2.id
    WHERE t2.id IS NULL OR t2.is_valid = false;

DELETE t1
    FROM t1
    WHERE t1.id IN (SELECT id FROM TheDeletedIds);
```

Then the table you just created has the ids you want.

Note:  It is important to use the newly-created table for the deletion.  Otherwise, another thread/process could change the data between the time you capture the ids and the time you delete them.

Comment: Looks like I cannot avoid creating a temporary table for doing this. Thank you!

Comment: In Postgres it's possible to put a DELETE statement inside a WITH clause and then SELECT the deleted rows out of it -- I don't suppose that's possible now in MySQL 8.0?  I assume not, since the DELETE statement has to have RETURNING *...

Comment: @Andy. . . I don't think that is possible in any other database.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
DELETE t1 OUTPUT DELETED.*
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 on (t1.t2_id = t2.id)
WHERE t2.id IS NULL OR t2.is_valid = false
```