# is it possible to get specific column value, which we are deleting

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to write a "SINGLE QUERY", by which i can delete row by id and get the name of deleted row.
For example: I have a table

```
id | Name
------------
1  | ABC
2  | DEF
3  | GIH
4  | JKL
```

Edit:
My question is not duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33115526/in-mysql-can-i-return-deleted-rows-after-a-deletion). I am again mentioning, I am trying to write "SINGLE QUERY".

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, hello madhur bhaiya, I am searching for single query, if its possible

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: *"Edit: My question is not duplicate of this. I am again mentioning, I am trying to write "SINGLE QUERY"."* Long answer to add to @MadhurBhaiya 's comment .. You will have to program your own [MySQL Server Plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-plugins.html) to extend default execution then you can do it in one query..

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks for your valuable guidance.